# jquery metisMenu not working inside ng-include

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-ng-include

I want to use *ng-include* to render the sidebar of the [template](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-2/). The template requires *jQuery metisMenu plugin* for dropdowns.

**Issue**: Plugin only **works** when I load the following scripts **inside the partial** template 'sidebar.html':

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/1.1.0/metisMenu.js"></script>

<script>$(function() {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
});</script>
```

and **fails** when I try to load them **inside index.html**.

I want to load the plugin only once inside *index.html* as I may require it in other partials as well. Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9wj0LSZgMHdo4HBvDa8s?p=preview) of the working model which requires script loading inside partials. Note that on moving scripts from *sidebar.html* to *index.html* the dropdown menu stops working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem. You need add metisMenu(); in your main controller:

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, Config) {
  $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't work on `index.html` because when it's fired the side-menu isn't present yet. This is the way to fire the jQuery method after AngularJS get's the partial for site

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/1.1.0/metisMenu.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  var $browser = app.injector().get('$browser');

  $browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function () {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I made changes as per your suggestion. Dropdown still wouldn't work without scripts inside the partial.[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m3ojOsHuxeyDTZYvX7eJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a link object that called $(element).metisMenu() inside of a setTimeout function fixed it for me.

```
app.directive('sideNav', function() {
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'side_nav.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       // execute metisMenu plugin
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(element).metisMenu();
        }, 1);
    },
    controller: function(){
        this.selectedNav = {};

        this.selectTab = function(setTab){
            this.tab = setTab;
        };
        this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
            return checkTab === this.tab;
        };

        this.navItems = [{
            name: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'fa-dashboard'
        },{
            name: 'Logs',
            icon: 'fa-code'
        },{
            name: 'Firm Diagnostics',
            icon: 'fa-stethoscope',
            navItems: [
                {
                    name: 'Disk I/O'
                },{
                    name: 'Disk Space'
                },{
                    name: 'Processor Information'
                },{
                    name: 'Processor Activity'
                },{
                    name: 'Memory Information'
                },{
                    name: 'Memory Usage'
                },{
                    name: 'Network Configuration'
                },{
                    name: 'Processes'
                },{
                    name: 'Services'
                },{
                    name: 'System Information'
                }
            ]
        }];

    },

    controllerAs: 'sideNav'
};});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add onload callback function at ng-include

```
<div ng-include="'sidebar.html'" onload="loaded()"></div>
```

and call metisMenu function in loaded function

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.loaded = function() {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
}
});
```

This is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KizxGtqLDlzWVYYHIKKV?p=preview)