# jQuery scripts not working in ng-include files

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have some logics in template.js file for whole application.
and if i start 'cutting' applications by parts and including its using ng-include, **jQuery 'logics' (from template.js) not working for included files**, but work if i paste it in included files, but in this way i have duplicate template.js in DOM.

example:

```
index.html 
<html>
    <head>
        <...jQuery, angularJs, etc...>
        <script scr="template.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Example dropdown</div>
        <div ng-include="file1.html"></div>
    </body>
</html>

file1.html
<div>Example dropdown</div>
```

'Example dropdown' in index.html works but same 'Example dropdown' in file1.html not working. 
And it works on this way:

```
index.html
<html>
    <head>
        <...jQuery, angularJs, etc...>
        <script scr="template.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Example dropdown</div>
        <div ng-include="file1.html"></div>
    </body>
</html>

file1.html
<script scr="template.js">
<div>Example dropdown</div>
```

but as we can see in this way we recieve duplicated template.js in DOM when all will be loaded.

How i can avoid duplicate using .js files and working upper example?

Same question: [jquery metisMenu not working inside ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335696/jquery-metismenu-not-working-inside-ng-include)

Comment: imho, it is not a good idea to use both jquery and angular. Try to do everything the angular way. jquery is good for manipulating DOM, use it for that purpose

Comment: yep, thinking about porting jquery logics to angular directives, but also wanna know other existing ways